# How can I extract all the strings inside {} via sed

Tags: sed

How can I extract all the strings inside `{}` via `sed`

```
{}
{A}
{
BC
D
}
```

expected output:

```
//empty line
A
BC
D
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With GNU sed:

```
sed 's/{\(.*\)}/\1/;/^[{}]$/d' file
```

Output:

```
A
BC
D
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
echo $str | cut -d "{" -f2 | cut -d "}" -f1
```